# Angular migration 12 to 14 running nx serve <app_name> failed

Tags: angular, migration, nrwl-nx, angular14, nomachine-nx

After migration angular version from 12 to 14 according this [guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-14.0), I'm can't run my app.

after successful build, I'm running this command: `nx serve <my app name>` and nothing happend.

[image]

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

choose nx version according to angular version that you want to upgrade in this guide:
https://nx.dev/angular-nx-version-matrix

run command:
`nx migrate 14.4.3`

(14.4.3 is nx version that upgrade to angular to v14)

than run:
`nx migrate --run-migrations`

and than:
`nx serve <my app name>`

- if you have this err: "NX spawn ENAMETOOLONG" or "NX Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')"

step 1: add **.angular** to .gitignore

step 2: commit the changes

that work for me.